# Let $Y,Z$ be idd. RV's, $\ Z \sim e(1), \ Y \sim R(0,1)$. Find $f_{X,Y}$ for $(X,Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y,Z$ be idd. RV's, $\ Z \sim e(1), \ Y \sim R(0,1), \ X = \frac Z Y$.

(*$R(0,1)$ denote the continuous uniform distribution*)

**Compute $P(X>1)$:**

I have $P(X>1) = 1-P(X \le 1) = 1 - P(Z\le Y) = 1 - \int^{\frac 1 2}_0 \int^y_0 \frac {e^{-z}} 2 \ dz \ dy = 0.426$

(*Please tell me if you disagree*).

**Find $f_{X,Y}$ for $(X,Y)$ using the transformation theorem:**

In order to apply a transformation I must know $f_{X,Y}$ ? As I look it up I have $$\int \int_A f(x,y) \ dx \ dy = \int \int_B f(w_1(u,v),w_2(u,v)) |J| \ du \ dv$$

Have I misunderstood something ? How can I find $f_{X,Y}$ using this ?

Comment: What is $X$?${}$

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I have now updated properly.

Comment: $(X,Y)=g(Z,Y)$ with $g(z,y)=(z/y,y)$ and you know $f_{Z,Y}$ by independence.

Comment: Could you write it more explicitly in terms of the one-to-one functions ?

Comment: What do you mean? The one-to-one function is $g$.

Comment: Ohh, I guess I'd not understood it correctly then, because I was looking for $w_1(u,v), w_2(u,v)$ and then computing the Jacobian of these.

Comment: How do I proceed with your function $g$ ? Now I don't have two functions to compute the Jacobian  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint density of $(Z,Y)$ is
$$
f_{Z,Y}(z,y)=\mathrm{e}^{-z}\mathbf{1}_{0<z}\mathbf{1}_{0<y<1}
$$
by independence. The vector $(X,Y)$ is obtained by transformation of $(Z,Y)$ by the one-to-one function $g(z,y)=(z/y,y)$. Now $g$ has inverse function $h(x,y)=(xy,y)$ and if we let $h_1(x,y)=xy$ and $h_2(x,y)=y$ denote the coordinate functions, then the Jacobian of $h$ is
$$
J(x,y)=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}(x,y) & \frac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}(x,y) \\
\frac{\partial h_2}{\partial x}(x,y) & \frac{\partial h_2}{\partial y}(x,y)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y & x \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has determinant $\det J(x,y)=y$. Thus the density of $(X,Y)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)&=|\det J(x,y)|f_{Z,Y}(h(x,y))=|y| f_{Z,Y}(xy,y)\\
&=y\mathrm{e}^{-xy}\mathbf{1}_{0<xy}\mathbf{1}_{0<y<1}=y\mathrm{e}^{-xy}\mathbf{1}_{0<y<1}\mathbf{1}_{0<x}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: Stefan, if $Y \sim R(0,1)$ then $0 \le y \le 1$ right ? Why strict inequlity ? Also in the case of $0 \le y \le 1$ how does one justify $h_1, h_2$ are continuous then ? Continuity is not defined on boundary points according to my calculus book, so how can these be continuously differentiable ??

Comment: It doesn't matter if you say $0\leq y\leq 1$ or $0<y<1$ since if $Y_1$ has density $\mathbf{1}_{0<y<1}$ and $Y_2$ has density $\mathbf{1}_{0\leq y\leq 1}$ then $Y_1\sim Y_2$.

Comment: Thank you Stefan. What exactly does the notation $Y_1 \sim Y_2$ mean ? So your point is: we can always remove the boundary of the region $R$ in order to get a region $R^{'}$ that satisfies the definition of continuously differentiable of $h_1,h_2$ without violation of the computed probability ? However $Y_2$ has density equal $= 0$ at $y=0$, while $Y_1$ has density $\neq 0$ at $y=0$. Isn't this a violation even thus the probability computed by the integral stays the same ? I mean the densities are different ?

Comment: The notation $Y_1\sim Y_2$ means that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ has the same distribution, i.e. $P(Y_1\in A)=P(Y_2\in A)$ for all nice subsets $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. The point is that for a random variable $X$ with density $f_X$ you may change the density in a finite number of points without changing the distribution of $X$. For instance, if we know that $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\tfrac12 x^2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ except for $x=2,4,6,283$, then I still know that $X$ follows a standard normal distribution .

Comment: Once again, thanks Stefan.

Comment: So it was on purpose you dropped these two values for $Y$ in order to get an open region where the theorem of transformation does apply ?

Comment: No. This is just the definition of a uniformly distributed variable I happen to be using.

Comment: But you agree that if these two values wasn't dropped we couldn't use the transformation theorem right, since the partial derivatives must be continuous, which is only defined on open region $R$.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous) The distribution includes the endpoints according to this.

Comment: Continuity is defined on any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for that matter), not just open subsets. So I do not see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

$(X,Y) = g(Z,Y)$ with $g(z,y) = (z/y,y)$.

So we have $x = z/y$ and $y = y$. Thus we can form the functions $w_1(x,y)=xy=z$ and $w_2(x,y)=y=y$.

The Jacobian is $|J| = | y \cdot 1 - 0 \cdot x | = |y |$.

So we have $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = f_{(Z,Y)}(w_1(x,y), w_2(x,y)) |J| = 2e^{-xy}|y|$ which is the same as $2e^{-xy}y$ because of the new domain.

Comment: Nice that you managed to solve it yourself. But from where is that factor of 2 coming? You also need to specify for which values of $x,y$ that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is zero.

Comment: The factor is $2$ is comming from $Y \sim R(0,\frac 1 2)$ - I noticed this later, but still I can apply what I've learned here.